# How to set excel header font and style in print preview?

Tags: header, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I'm using iReport 5.6.0 for creating a report,
I want to add a header for excel when print preview, I tried adding this line in the jrxml

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.header.left" value="My Left Text"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.header.center" value="My Center Text"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.header.right" value="My Right Text"/>
```

This is working fine, but the problem is I don't know how to add font style or font size.

Is there a way that I can add font style, font size, or font color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Jasper report has no attribute in which you can specify the font used for header.

*but we can do some crazy stuff*

Jasper report is using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) to export to excel, in POI to set the page header, commands like this is used (see [HSSFHeader](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFHeader.html))

```
header.setCenter(HSSFHeader.font("Calibri", "bold") + HSSFHeader.fontSize((short) 16) + "My Center Text");
```

This is actually generating a String that is set to center.

```
&"Calibri,bold"&16My Center Text
```

Since we need to put it in an xml attribute we need to escape `"` with `&quot;` and `&` with `&amp;`.

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.header.center" 
         value="&amp;&quot;Calibri,bold&quot;&amp;16My Center Text"/>
```

**Voilà**

[image: Result]

To understand how the String should be when switching from different style and using other POI attributes, an easiest way is to make a small java program, for example

```
System.out.println(HSSFHeader.font("Times New Roman", "regular") + 
         HSSFHeader.fontSize((short) 12) + "My " + HSSFHeader.startBold() + "Bold" + 
         HSSFHeader.endBold() + " Text with date " + HSSFHeader.date());
```

> &"Times New Roman,regular"&12My &BBold&B Text with date &D

<sup>just escape and insert into to value attribute</sup>

Comment: thanks its working! but is it possible to add image?

Comment: @endyeyEs POI (the lib generating excel) has limited support for header and footer, AFIK we can't push it any futher, I even doubt using a template with image in header will work, but maybe it's worth a try.